# While loop int value won't update

Tags: java, multithreading, while-loop, int

```
public class Loader implements Runnable{
    int players;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Loader Loader = new Loader();
        Loader.initiate();
    }
    public void initiate(){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Loader());
        t1.start();

        while(true){
            players++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            System.out.println(players);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So when I activate a thread broadcaster to broadcast the amount of players, I can't add to the players int value and have it be broadcasted...

players = 0
when a player logs on --> players++;
but when it broadcasts the amount of players its still 0...

Comment: Please post code here, not a link to code.  Please also cut your code down to a [**minimal** test-case](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem, and tell us what debugging you've attempted so far.  Please also add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: Why does this look incredibly like Java?

Comment: I don't see any C++ here.

Comment: Especially the line `System.out.println`.

Comment: Someone else tagged it C++

Comment: Replace C++ tag with Java.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews my bad, I was too hasty :(

Answer (score 3):

You create two instances of the `Loader` class. You execute

```
players++;
```

in one instance and expect it to be updated in the other as well...

Replace

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Loader());
```

with

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(this);
```

and it *might* work better... (but I suspect there are some other issues as well)

**Edit**: As commented by [Peter Lawrey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/57695/peter-lawrey), in your example situation `players` need to be declared `volatile`:

```
volatile int players;
```

Both threads are using the variable, the compiler/Java VM does not know this and might cache the result of `players` which might/will mess with the actual and expected value (depending in which Thread your are). Declaring the variable as volatile, makes sure that `players`is not cached and when required its value is grabbed from memory.

Additional: you might want to use `synchronize` to make sure only one Thread is accessing the variable at the same time. This also prevent problems with unexpected values. Especially, when multiple threads are *writing* the variable.

Comment: What if the threads running method is another class and I'm executing the thread from another class

Comment: You need to call a function of the other class to provide the updated player count

Comment: @PeterLawrey Good point, although the example seems to be simplified and the OP has 2 classes. I'll update my answer

Comment: @PeterLawrey is it compulsory?

Comment: @joeyrohan if you want correctness, yes.  Without volatile the reading thread will be optimised away as the thread doesn't change the value.

Comment: @PeterLawrey might not change value, or won't change value?

Comment: @joeyrohan The value is effectively copied into a code local variable, so it no longer sees changes.

Comment: Thanks for all you help and suggestions but I looked at this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html
and got my answer. The solution was to change int players to static int players so all instances could access the newly update variable